# Error installing Simple.Odata via nuget on a PCL

Tags: odata, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, simple.odata

I have a PCL targeting .Net 4.5, Silverlight 4+, Windows Phone 7.5+, .Net for windows store apps, Mono Android and MonoTouch

I am attempting to install Simple.OData via nuget and getting the error below. I have tried many different combinations, but nothing seems to be able to pull down the library. My main goal is to develop for Android and Touch using MVVMCross and Odata services.

```
PM> Install-Package Simple.OData.Client
Installing 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'.
Successfully installed 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'.
Adding 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0' to EMC.Mobile.Core.
Uninstalling 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'portable-win+net403+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Simple.OData.Client
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: You might be aiming to target .net45, but that trace clearly shows `net403`? Maybe try a new PCL project - maybe try manually editing the csproj to force it into profile104 or profile78

Comment: I tried .Net 4.5, and still get the same error. I see that the project is already set to Profile104 <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile104</TargetFrameworkProfile>.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client it says the package only supports Windows Phone 8 and higher - so I guess your problem is Windows Phone 7.5 is not supported.

Comment: But there is no way to comment out Windows 7.5. Even if I unselect everything except MonoAndroid and MonoTouch on the 'Change Target Frameworks' dialog, after I hit 'OK', .Net 4.5, SL4+ and Win Phone 7.5+ are automatically selected.

Comment: @JohnBliss That is probably happening because you only put the MonoAndroid and MonoTouch xml files in one of the portable profile folders.  Unselect those two frameworks in the choose target frameworks dialog, then see what profile you end up referencing.  To do this select the ".NET Portable Subset" node in the references of your project in solution explorer, then look at the Path for it in the properties Window.  Add the MonoAndroid/MonoTouch xml files to the SupportedFrameworks folder under that path, and then restart VS and change your library to target the platforms you want.

Comment: OK, so I removed MonoTouch and MonoAndroid from the list of frameworks and then checked the path of the .Net Portable Subset in References. I had Profile4. So I moved the MonoTouch and MonoAndroid xml files in the Profile4 folder. Yet, I cannot install Simple.OData nuget package. The error is the same: Could not install package 'Simple.OData.Client 0.16.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework

Comment: @JohnBliss: You need to select a profile that supports the following platforms, or a more restrictive set: .NET 4.0.3, Windows Store, Silverlight 5, and Windows Phone 8.  Profile147 is the profile that Simple.OData.Client targets.

Answer (score 0):

Just to want to let you know that there is a new version (0.17) of Simple.OData.Client with changes that affect MonoTouch/MonoDroid.

However, as Stuart and Daniel pointed out, you must select compatible PCL profile. Make sure that your selected profile doesn't select earlier versions of Silverlight and Windows Phone.

Let me know if you need more help with this.